# Set text color based on theme - android/kotlin error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-theme

I am trying to change the color of text in a fragment based on the currently active theme. But the app keeps crashing with the following error

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff000000
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:237)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:1059)
    at android.content.Context.getColor(Context.java:677)
```

My code is below:

```
bind.scrollDate.setTextColor(view.context.getColor(if (day.date == selectedDate) R.color.white else getColorByThemeAttr(requireContext(),R.attr.txtcolor,R.color.txtcolor)))

    //getting colors based on theme
private fun getColorByThemeAttr(context: Context, attr: Int, defaultColor: Int): Int {
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    val theme: Resources.Theme = context.theme
    val got: Boolean = theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValue, true)
    return if (got) typedValue.data else defaultColor
}
```

I understand that using the right context in fragment is important, but have tried multiple variations with none working....

Any solution for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, TypedValue will not be resource id, but value. This means that you should change call to this:

```
    a.setTextColor(if (1!=1) view.context.getColor(R.color.colorAccent) else getColorByThemeAttr(requireContext(),R.attr.txtColor,R.color.color2))
```

And your method to something like this:

```
private fun getColorByThemeAttr(context: Context, attr: Int, defaultColor: Int): Int {
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    val theme: Resources.Theme = context.theme
    val got: Boolean = theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValue, true)
    return if (got) typedValue.data else context.getColor(defaultColor)
}
```